# Setting timeout on jQuery's get shorthand

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timeout

Is it possible to set the ajax timeout parameter using jQuery's get shorthand?  If not, do requests sent with the shorthand ever timeout?

```
jQuery.get(
    url, 
    [ data ], 
    [ callback(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ], 
    [ dataType ] 
)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

> Is it possible to set the ajax timeout parameter using jQuery's get shorthand?

No, not *per request*, though you can use [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to do it for *all* requests.

> If not, do requests sent with the shorthand ever timeout?

No, by default they won't (unless you used [`$.ajaxSetup({ timeout: value });`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)), the default [`timeout`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) option [isn't defined](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L476), the same as `0` meaning "don't timeout".

---

To do a timeout *per request* and not globally, you'd have to switch to the longhand format:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: callback(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest),
  dataType: dataType,
  timeout: timeoutvalue
});
```